# Condition if else in karate framework

Tags: karate

```
How can I create an if else condition with several steps with the karate framework in a scenario?
Knowing that in the if and the else there would be calls to other scenarios?

I saw this:
* def num = 5
* if num == 5
*   print 'num is 5'
* else
*   print 'num is not 5'

But it does not work
```

I try to create an if else condition in karate framework